# Windows 10 Windows Explorer Remove Quick Access

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10-preview

In Windows 10 how do I *remove* "Quick Access" altogether from the Windows Explorer navigation panel?

I do *not* want to add/remove items to the menu, I want to remove it outright in the similar fashion to [Windows Explorer Navigation Pane Configuration](http://www.s-inn.de/blog/post/remove-Libraries-Favorites-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane.aspx).

Comment: I've deleted my answer but can you explain what you mean by "it didn't work"? Was Quick access not affected at all by changing those settings? What if anything was left behind? I'm sure there'll be a way to get rid of it by deleting the appropriate reg keys, but I don't have the latest build yet to experiment with and moreover any workaround might break with the next build anyway. Perhaps it might be best to wait till Win10 reaches the RC stage.

Comment: @Karan It's still there with nothing directly underneath it, the next item is Desktop. What I want would make the Desktop item at the very top. I used *Windows10_InsiderPreview_x64_EN-US_10074.iso* with all the latest Windows Updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of [Windows Explorer Navigation Pane Configuration](http://www.s-inn.de/blog/post/remove-Libraries-Favorites-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane.aspx) supports this. Open an administrative privileged command prompt and run the executable with the parameters specified in the PDF file. Log off and log back in for the changes to take effect.

---

I now use [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/). Since there is an extended number of tweaks copy the code and save it as a file called `Winaero Tweaker_2019_12_22.ini` which you can then easily import. Keep in mind my preferences may differ from those who try this.

```
[Format]
ProductName=Winaero Tweaker
ProductVersion=0.16.1.0
FormatVersion=1.1
[User]
pageAltTab10=1
pageAdsUnwantedApps=1
pageShutdownDialogDefaultAction=1
pageDisableLookInStore=1
pageDisableAutomaticMaintenance=1
pageDisableSafeZoneInformation=1
pageDisableMRT=1
pageDisableTimeline=1
pageErrorReporting=1
pageShowMenuDelay=1
pagePowerThrottling=1
pageShowBSODDetails=1
pageSvcHostSplitThreshold=1
pageSafeModeWindowsInstaller=1
pageLoginScreenBlur=1
pageDisableLockScreen=1
pageNumlockLoginState=1
pageBalloonTooltips=1
pageCortanaSearchBoxText=1
pageDisableNotificationCenter=1
pageDisableLiveTiles=1
pageDisableDriverUpdates10=1
pageQuickActionButtons=1
pageDisableWebSearch=1
pageOldVolumeControl=1
pageTaskbarPinMorePeople=1
pageTaskbarFlashCount=1
pageWallpaperQuality=1
pageContextMenuCmdAsAdmin=1
pageContextMenuRemoveDefault=1
pageContextMenuTakeOwnership=1
pageContextMenuCompactOS=1
pageControlPanelWU=1
pageDisableOnlineVideoTips=1
pageConfirmationCheckBoxDoForAll=1
pageDisableAutomaticFolderTypeDiscovery=1
pageCustomizeLibrariesItem=1
pageThisPCTweaker=1
pageDragDropAction=1
pageDisableSearchHistory=1
pageDriveLetters=1
pageNavPaneDefaultItems=1
pageNetworkComputers1803=1
pageLinkedConnections=1
pageEnableAdministrator=1
pageUAC=1
pageDefenderAntiMalware=1
pageDisableCortana=1
pageDisableWindowsInk=1
pageEdgePreloading=1
pageIEExtraButtons=1
pageDisableTelemetry=1
pageDisableShortcutText=1
pageShortcutArrow=1
pagePhotoViewer=1
[pageAltTab10]
Grid_backgroundPercent=70
BackgroundDimmingLayer_percent=0
Wallpaper=0
AltTabSettings=1
[pageAdsUnwantedApps]
UnwantedAppsDisabled=1
FileExplorerAdsDisabled=1
LockScreenAdsDisabled=1
StartSuggestionsDisabled=1
TipsAboutWindowsDisabled=1
WelcomePageDisabled=1
SettingsAdsDisabled=1
PeopleAdsDisabled=1
TimelineSuggestionsDisabled=1
[pageShutdownDialogDefaultAction]
ShutdownAction=64
[pageShowMenuDelay]
MenuShowDelay=0
[pageSvcHostSplitThreshold]
SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB=34507912
[pageCortanaSearchBoxText]
CortanaText= 
[pageTaskbarPinMorePeople]
TaskbarCapacity=0
[pageTaskbarFlashCount]
ForegroundFlashCount=3
[pageWallpaperQuality]
JPEGImportQuality=90
[pageContextMenuCmdAsAdmin]
contextMenuTitle=Command Prompt (Administrator)
Extended=0
[pageContextMenuRemoveDefault]
IsScanWithDefenderRemoved=1
IsCastToDeviceRemoved=1
IsBitLockerRemoved=1
IsEditWithPaint3DRemoved=1
IsExtractAllRemoved=1
IsBurnImageRemoved=1
IsShareWithRemoved=1
IsModernSharingRemoved=1
IsPreviousVersionsRemoved=1
IsPinToTaskbarRemoved=1
IsPinToStartRemoved=1
IsCompatibilityRemoved=1
IsIncludeInLibraryRemoved=1
IsRotateRightLeftRemoved=1
IsOneDriveRemoved=1
IsEFSRemoved=1
[pageCustomizeLibrariesItem]
LibrariesName=Libraries
LibrariesIconPath=C:\ProgramData\WinaeroTweaker\ShellIcons\1059646110.ico
[pageThisPCTweaker]
ThisPCFoldersCount=0
[pageDragDropAction]
DefaultDropEffect=2
[pageDriveLetters]
ShowDriveLettersFirst=4
[pageNavPaneDefaultItems]
{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}=0
{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}=0
{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}=0
{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}=1
{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}=1
{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}=0
[pageEdgePreloading]
AllowTabPreloading=0
AllowPrelaunch=0
[pageIEExtraButtons]
HideNewEdgeButton=0
NoHelpItemSendFeedback=1
[pageShortcutArrow]
ShortcutOverlayIcon=C:\ProgramData\WinaeroTweaker\ShellIcons\classic.ico
```

Comment: Way too hard to do.  "To Hide Quick Access" below works on Windows 10 Pro and also Windows Server 2019.

Comment: @DougNull Thanks for commenting, I've updated with the new method that I've been using for a while. Please try it out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

**To Hide Quick Access**,

1. Open File Explorer and go to View -> Options.
2. Under the General tab, change 'Open File Explorer to' from 'Quick access' to 'This PC'.

> **To Remove the Quick Access Feature Entirely**
>
> 1. You’ll need to edit the registry for this procedure.
> 2. Hide Quick Access using the steps in the above section.
> 3. Once that’s done, click windows start button and type regedit, right click and run as administrator.
> 4. Navigate to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}
> 5. Expand it, and right-click ShellFolder.
> 6. Select Permissions, and click the Advanced button.
> 7. In the 'Advanced Security Settings for ShellFolder' box, click the 'Change' link,
> 8. Then click 'Advanced',
> 9. Click the 'Find Now' button,
> 10. And in the 'Search results' box select 'Administrators'.
> 11. Click OK twice, then Apply, and hit OK until the boxes closes.
> 12. Make sure you allow Full Control (click)
> 13. Inside 'ShellFolder', double-click 'Attributes', and change data value to 'a0600000', then click OK.
> 14. With that done, reboot your PC.
> 15. When you open File Explorer next time, Quick Access should be gone.

**To Turn the Quick Access Feature Back On**

1. If you decide you want the feature back, repeat the process but change the ShellFolder attributes from 'a0600000' to 'a0100000', and click OK.

This solution worked for me, and was found [here at betanews](http://betanews.com/2015/07/31/remove-quick-access-from-file-explorer-in-windows-10/).

Comment: You answer is not very readable. Please can you reformat it to use numbering/bullets/etc. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it has this option as I've only briefly played with Win10, but Classic Shell is able to change a vast range of settings on Windows 7-10:

http://classicshell.net/

On Win8, I reckon this app makes the difference between having a headache and having a computer.

Comment: This is just a vague guess at best and would have been better off as a comment. If you can confirm that Classic Shell can actually do what the OP wants then I will gladly remove my negative vote.

Comment: I think it is quite reasonable to make a suggestion which may benefit the OP. I DID check the documentation before posting, and it looks like it might do this. If I were posting BS you would be within your rights to post neg FB, but I am not. Your reaction seems to be pure vindictiveness.

Comment: You can certainly make a suggestion but you're yourself unsure whether your suggestion is valid. Can you point out where in the docs it says Classic Shell can disable Quick Access? If you can provide some proof or better still a screenshot of it working, I'll definitely upvote your answer. Edit: Just saw you added a few sentences to your comment. For the record it's not vindictiveness because I don't know you from any Tom, Dick or Harry and I lose rep too when downvoting. Provide the proof that your answer (which BTW I never said was total BS) works and get the well-deserved upvote, simple.

Comment: I can confirm that Classic Shell has this option. It's in the Context Menu section. Though, tests seem to indicate that this setting may not work properly on Windows 10. Since My Win10 install was bashed-around a bit from software testing I wanted to wait until I could confirm this on a fresh install. They may fix this in due course.

Comment: So, I make a suggestion based on experience. An admin punishes me for making what he considers to be a guess. I then show that the information I am giving is in the software manual. Further testing (which involved me in a lot of additional time at my own expense) shows that the option might not work correctly, but that is hardly MY fault. I gave authentic information, and that is what matters. The punishment still stands. Sod that for a laugh, if I were being paid to give advice this would still be bad enough. As it is, foot-shooting exercise since I'm outa here.